# how to add three dots to text when overflow in html?

Tags: html, css

How can I show three dots(...) in a text like this?
[image: like this?]

Comment: The key word you need to search for is "ellipsis"

Comment: http://www.mobify.com/blog/multiline-ellipsis-in-pure-css/

Comment: Check this link for Cross-browser multiline ellipse. https://codepen.io/natonischuk/pen/QbGWBa

Answer (score 178):

Add all these.
To make in single line.

```css
{
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    width:100px; /* some width */
}
```

To do in multi line which actually you asked.

```css
#content {
    overflow: hidden;
    width:100px;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}
```

working fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/mishrarajesh/676jc7sa/

Please note that this multiline code is supported only in web-kit browsers for now.

Comment: But it shows only a single row

Comment: Please. Check my update.

Comment: @rajesh Is this css can be used in email format so i can make email responsive like your demo?

Comment: Yes of course..

Comment: it only works with webkit.. not working on firefox

Comment: This multiline version works only for webkit. At least answer should mention it.

Comment: works for me only when setting max-width