# Multiple dots for input html

Tags: css

I have a React component that encapsulates the input html tag. The default behaviour for input tag is if the characters are more than what the input can display, we can scroll to left and right with invisible scroll (e.g. I type John Smitheens for size 11).

[image]

I want to make the display change to John Smith... if the input is unfocused (not clicked).

[image]

I don't know the size or number of characters I want to limit beforehand because the React component is used in a lot of places and the size differs based on parent component (width: 100%). Is there a way to get the input size or know when the characters exceed the input width? Thank you

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <input placeholder="Search User" type="text" size="11">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your stylesheet :)

Add it to your  `input` css.

`text-overflow: ellipsis;`

Similar case here:

[how to add three dots to text when overflow in html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36652580/how-to-add-three-dots-to-text-when-overflow-in-html)

More on the topic:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow

Answer (score 1):

Just add `text-overflow: ellipsis;` to the input

```css
input {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <input placeholder="Search User" type="text" size="11">
</body>

</html>
```